# why blank requirement.txt in dockerfile

Tags: python, dockerfile, devops

I am working as a devops for a team(newly started and learning). And they have below code in dockerfile:

```
FROM docker.jfrog.io/folder/base-ml:0.1.0
COPY requirements.txt ./
COPY ./app.py ./
COPY ./features_names.json ./

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

requirements.txt is blank. The question is: can this part of having blank file be removed?
or this is mandatory to have requirements.txt file?

I have to suggest best practices to team in such cases.

Comment: Does anything bad happen if you remove the lines concerning the `requirements.txt`?

Comment: Have you tried asking them why they have it?

Comment: @GinoMempin is spot on - we can't say *why* your specific team has this setup. You really should ask your teammates.

Comment: I will ask why they have it like that...alongwith that I am looking for best practices to suggest to move it.

Comment: The best practice is to discuss what your teammates did with your teammates. Maybe they forgot to pip freeze the dependencies, so better do that. Maybe they forgot to delete the file, so better delete it as not needed. Maybe they are installing dependencies from another image, so better remove it. Maybe it's a template for how they structure all their apps and builds, so might be better to keep it.

Comment: @GinoMempin Thanks a lot for inputs.

Answer (score -1):

The file `requirements.txt` will contain all python dependencies that are needed in your container. It is not mandatory, you may also install each dependency with the `pip` commmand. Of course, if you have many dependencies, the use of `requirements.txt` makes the docker file cleaner.

Comment: so, since it is blank. can it be removed all together. if we talk about best practices, is this right place to have it or can this be moved? Like they have base image for their ML service. Do you suggest moving it to base image coould be cleaner?

Comment: Yes, since it is blank, makes no sense to use it. More in general, my answer is it depends. If you have Python dependencies that can be shared across their ML services, I believe that it is correct to have requirements in the base image. Conversely, if the base image needs to be specialized into low level images, requirements may be binded to them depending on their needs.